# How to toggle a class among some different elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the html I have 2 images within the `.fig-8` anchor.

`.img-active` = `display: block`

`.img-inactive` = `display: none`

HTML:

```
<div class="tabs1">
    <a class="fig-8" data-tab="tab1">
       <img src="/path.png" class="img-active">
       <img src="/selected.png" class="img-inactive">
    </a>

    <a class="fig-8" data-tab="tab2">
       <img src="/path1.png" class="img-active">
       <img src="/selected.png" class="img-inactive">
    </a>

    <a class="fig-8" data-tab="tab3">
       <img src="/path2.png" class="img-active">
       <img src="/selected.png" class="img-inactive">
    </a>
</div>
```

All I need is that when you click on the anchor, `.img-active` should be `display: none` and `.img-inactive` = `display: block`

As I am doing it in the js file:

```
$('.tabs1 a').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('.img-active').hide();
    $(this).find('.img-inactive').show();
});
```

It is doing what I want but if you click on the second or third anchor, the images where I clicked are not getting to its original shape(the default image.).

Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean by original shape?

Comment: @VivekN the image that was before. The default one.

Comment: Bah, can't remember jQuery. Basically, you want to find everyone, hide them, then find the target of the click and show that one.

Comment: Why not tie into the css `:focus` pseudo-class?  Something like `.tabs1 a:focus .img-inactive { display: block; }` and `.tabs1 a:focus .img-active { display: none; }`

Comment: @TheUnnamed Try the answer that I have posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't this be achieved using CSS?  You can use the `:focus` pseudo-class.

```css
.img-inactive,.img-active {float:left;}
.img-inactive {display:none;}
.img-active {display:block;}

a:focus .img-inactive {display:block;}
a:focus .img-active {display:none;}
```

```html
<div class="tabs1">
    <a class="fig-8" data-tab="tab1" href="#">
       <img src="//placehold.it/150/5C5/FFF?&text=active" class="img-active">
       <img src="//placehold.it/150/C55/FFF?&text=inactive" class="img-inactive">
    </a>

    <a class="fig-8" data-tab="tab2" href="#">
       <img src="//placehold.it/150/5C5/FFF?&text=active" class="img-active">
       <img src="//placehold.it/150/C55/FFF?&text=inactive" class="img-inactive">
    </a>

    <a class="fig-8" data-tab="tab3" href="#">
       <img src="//placehold.it/150/5C5/FFF?&text=active" class="img-active">
       <img src="//placehold.it/150/C55/FFF?&text=inactive" class="img-inactive">
    </a>
</div>
```

Otherwise, it's also pretty easy to do with jQuery

```js
$('.tabs1 a').on('click', function() {
    $('.tabs1 a .img-inactive').hide();
    $('.tabs1 a .img-active').show();
    $(this).find('.img-inactive').show();
    $(this).find('.img-active').hide();
});
```

```css
.img-inactive,.img-active {float:left;}
.img-inactive {display:none;}
.img-active {display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs1">
    <a class="fig-8" data-tab="tab1" href="#">
       <img src="//placehold.it/150/5C5/FFF?&text=active" class="img-active">
       <img src="//placehold.it/150/C55/FFF?&text=inactive" class="img-inactive">
    </a>

    <a class="fig-8" data-tab="tab2" href="#">
       <img src="//placehold.it/150/5C5/FFF?&text=active" class="img-active">
       <img src="//placehold.it/150/C55/FFF?&text=inactive" class="img-inactive">
    </a>

    <a class="fig-8" data-tab="tab3" href="#">
       <img src="//placehold.it/150/5C5/FFF?&text=active" class="img-active">
       <img src="//placehold.it/150/C55/FFF?&text=inactive" class="img-inactive">
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:-

```
$('.tabs1 a').on('click', function() {
    $('.img-active').not(this).show();
    $('.img-inactive').not(this).hide();
    $(this).find('.img-active').hide();
    $(this).find('.img-inactive').show();
});
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit why that `.not` there?

Comment: So if I understand your problem correctly, you wanted to bring all the previous images back to how they were and the currently clicked one as different.So I am bringing all other images except this(which is the currently clicked one) to there original state and the $(this) one the way you want which is display: none for .img-active and display:block  for .img-inactive